# attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I have this crash.

I have tried everything. I have searched in Google for 3 days to understand why my app crashes, and I didn't find anything.
I found a lot of similar posts, tried to used some from here and there, but still getting a crash.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update'
>    First throw call stack:

My .m file:

```
#import "PlayersViewController.h"
#import "Player.h"
#import "PlayerCell.h"

@interface PlayersViewController ()
@end

@implementation PlayersViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PlayerCell *cell = (PlayerCell *)[tableView
                                      dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PlayerCell"];
    Player *player = [self.players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text = player.name;
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [self.players removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}

- (void)playerDetailsViewControllerDidCancel:
    (PlayerDetailsViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)playerDetailsViewControllerDidSave:
    (PlayerDetailsViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddPlayer"])
    {
        UINavigationController *navigationController =
        segue.destinationViewController;
        PlayerDetailsViewController
        *playerDetailsViewController =
        [[navigationController viewControllers]
         objectAtIndex:0];
        playerDetailsViewController.delegate = self;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.players count];
}

- (void)playerDetailsViewController:
(PlayerDetailsViewController *)controller
                       didAddPlayer:(Player *)player
{
    [self.players addObject:player];

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.5];

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

[image]

I hope you can help.

Answer (score 3):

Have you give the cell identifier to PlayerCell from storyboard? Define viewDidLoad method in your .m file.

I your  .h file add delegate and datasource for table view, Like UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDlegate.

After that in your  .m file and in viewDidLoad method add,

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
[self.tableView setDataSource : self];
```

This might help you.

You can log the array of players and see it is not nil.
For your player methods and logic make new model file and write player logic there and import it in your table view.

Comment: Try to remove begin Update and end update and then run the app again. @user1071269

Comment: I tried, and still the same crash with the same error.

Comment: when you are calling this method? '- (void)playerDetailsViewController:
(PlayerDetailsViewController *)controller
                       didAddPlayer:(Player *)player' @user1071269

Comment: I have a .m file where i have this method 

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
 Player *player = [[Player alloc] init];
 player.name = self.nameTextField.text;
 [self.delegate playerDetailsViewController:self
                                  didAddPlayer:player];
}

then this method is called 

- (void)playerDetailsViewController: (PlayerDetailsViewController *)controller didAddPlayer:(Player *)player

Comment: So in this tableView controller .m file you have declared this method?

Comment: change add in row : 0 to 1 and try. because in ios 8 sometimes rows start from 1. @user1071269

Comment: I have a PlayerDetailsViewController.m file where I have this method - (IBAction)done:(id)sender, when this is clicked, this class is called PlayersViewController.m and there I have this method - (void)playerDetailsViewController:
(PlayerDetailsViewController *)controller
                       didAddPlayer:(Player *)player

Comment: changed it from 0 to 1, and it still crashed

Comment: If I only add beginupdate and not endupdate, then it doesn't crash, but it doesn't add the player name.

Comment: Have you use reloadData instead of beginUpdate and endUpdate? @user1071269

Comment: I removed beginUpdate, and added reloadData to viewdidLoad, and still crashes.

Comment: remove '[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]' and only write, NSIndexPath *indexPath; And in arrayWithObject:indexPath.row. @user1071269

Comment: Still not working for me, is it possible, that i can send you the whole project, maybe you can look at it ?

Comment: Yes but not today. I will look at your code tomorrow. @user1071269

Comment: I figured out the problem, but now I am trying to save my data, when the app starts again, any idea how ?

Answer (score 0):

Between beginUpdates and endUpdates you must modify both the tableview and the datasource in a matching way. You don't do that. You only modify the tableview.

And I'd recommend to learn and use the Objective-C array syntax and Objective-C literals. "[self.players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]" becomes "self.players [indexPath.row]" and "[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]" becomes "@[indexPath]".

Comment: That's basic programming. I showed you the bug, you can fix it yourself. Seriously.

Comment: Which is your data source? (Hint: It's the thing that tells you how many sections and rows you have). How does it know how many rows you have? It knows by looking at some data, in your case players.count. You need to modify its data (players) between beginUpdates and endUpdates so that it will return the right number of rows after you call endUpdates.